# Best strategy for knowing newly added/updated rows in Hbase

Tags: hbase

I need to know what are the rows which are newly added/updated/deleted in HBase table.
Consider I have a seperate table in which I am maintaining this changes list (ie the keys which have changed) , and there is a flag which tells this is a changed row (0 - Changed, 1 - changed row processed).

There is another process which is interested in knowing changed rows, and once it has processed the rows it will update the rows to 1.
Whats the best strategy to do it in hbase.

Answer (score 0):

While inserting a row, if you set timestamp as curr date, you can find newly added rows by using TimestampFilter. To trace what has changed for a specific rowkey/value you can use Version ability of hbase.